# Django: is it a good idea to user DRF's Serializer rather than native Django forms to create forms

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django. I was working on a webapp which has lot of forms. I used Django's Native Form class to create and validate forms.

Now the same application i want to create api endpoints. When i was going through Django rest Framework, i found that Serializers are similar to Forms.

But for sake of api end points again i have to write all the validation login i created in Forms.

What i was feeling is can i shift to DRF and completely avoid Forms so that my forms and also the api end points both are taken care.

Comment: Then it would become a single page app, which requires a JS frontend.

Comment: it even supports html and forms. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/. I am not sure whether it supports formsets